# I am using FBLogInView to implement FBLogin. loginViewFetchedUserInfo not getting called

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have spent several hours. Read up everything relevant I could find on the web, but haven't been able to resolve this. I am using FBLoginView per instructions provided in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-ui-control/

I can see FBLogin button. I click on it. It logs me in. I see callbacks loginViewShowingLoggedInUser and loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser getting called. The problem is loginViewFetchedUserInfo not getting called. So, I am unable to get any information about the user (such as name, userID, email etc).

Here is the code I am using:

```
CGRect loginFrame=CGRectMake(MARGIN,currentFrame.size.height-LOGINBUTTONHEIGHT,50 , 20);//width, height don't matter
FBLoginView * FBLoginView1 = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
FBLoginView1.readPermissions =    @[@"email",
                                 @"basic_info",
                                 @"user_location",
                                 @"user_birthday",
                                 @"user_likes"];
FBLoginView1.frame = loginFrame;
FBLoginView1.delegate = self;
[[self view] addSubview:FBLoginView1];

[FBLoginView1 sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually, loginViewFetchedUserInfo is called after loginViewShowingLoggedInUser. I was not getting loginViewFetchedUserInfo because I was dismissing modalviewcontroller from loginViewShowingLoggedInUser. So, it was not around to get loginViewFetchedUserInfo. If I don't dismiss the modalviewcontroller, I get loginViewFetchedUserInfo.

Here are the details of the solution.
I am creating FBLoginView in ViewDidLoad of a LoginViewcontroller (name of the class I implemented).
I set the delegate when I create FBLoginView (inside ViewDidLoad function)
LoginViewController is presented using presentViewController function.
The problem was happening because I was dismissing the view controller in loginViewShowingLoggedInUser. So it was not around to receive loginViewFetchedUserInfo ( loginViewFetchedUserInfo is called after loginViewShowingLoggedInUser).

The solution that worked for me is to dismiss LoginViewcontroller from loginViewFetchedUserInfo.

Hope the details helps others.

Answer (score 4):

It may help: I have get the same issue. For me the solution was I did not correctly assign the delegate.
Programmatically, Facebook propose you to

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginView.delegate = self;
```

But as I have set up the view via the storyboard, I could not do that. So in the inspector connector, I connect the delegate outlet to the File's Owner (I just wired the outlet the scene).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i just Did it by adding 
(
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
    self.loginButton.delegate = self;) to viewDidLoad and my button (
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginButton;
)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, `delegate` was not set properly. Ensure you the following lines in `logincontroller`:

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginView.delegate = self;
```